# Как реализовать на Node js проверку авторизации полученых с помощью виджета авторизации Telegram

Tags: node.js, telegram, oauth

Не получается реализовать проверку данных авторизации через Телеграм виджет. В документации Телеграм (https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login) описано как происходит проверка хеша с данными и ссылка на пример с образцом кода на РНР, но у меня возникли трудности с реализацией подобного функционала на Node.Js!

```
data_check_string = ...
secret_key = SHA256(<bot_token>)
if (hex(HMAC_SHA256(data_check_string, secret_key)) == hash) {
  // data is from Telegram
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: вот есть код https://github.com/mghiozzi/node-telegram-login/blob/master/src/telegram-login.ts. вот есть статья https://edisonchee.com/writing/telegram-login-with-node.js/ и код https://github.com/edisonchee/telegram-login-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью такой реализации

```
async function checkTgAuth({ hash, ...userData}) {
  const secretKey = crypto.createHash('sha256')
    .update(config.token)
    .digest();
  const dataCheckString = Object.keys(userData)
    .sort()
    .map(key => (`${key}=${userData[key]}`))
    .join('\n');
  const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secretKey)
    .update(dataCheckString)
    .digest('hex');
  return hmac === hash;
}
```